# How I filter SQL using curdate? (example: registers that column "created_date" are more than 180 ago) (responsys - oracle)

Tags: sql, oracle, time, filter, responsys

I need to filter my list based on date time.

**Example:** "people who purchased 180 days ago"

However I need that the comparison be with actual date (system date), so that I don't have to filter manually every day.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Subtract `180` from (truncated?) `SYSDATE`:

```
select whatever
from your_table
where date_column < trunc(sysdate) - 180;
```

Why truncate? Becuase `sysdate` function returns both date and time, so - you'd probably want to "remove" the time component.

Comment: I tried: "Select * from $A$ where CREATED_DATE_ > trunc(sysdate) - 50;" for a test, but doesn't work. The result show registers with "2020-04-24 07:02:15.443" (less than 50)

Comment: What does "doesn't work" mean? Any error? If so, which one? What is CREATED_DATE column's datatype? Should be **DATE** in order for that query to work properly

Comment: Means "no error" kkk, the search gets my consult, but the registers per si wasn't what i was expecting. I found registers from today in the result!, i just only results with created date more than today

Comment: Huh, this is difficult to understand. "per si"? Anyway: do you mean that you want to fetch values which were created e.g. 181, 182, ... 200, 500, ... days ago? My query shows those which were created during the last 180 days (i.e. simplified, during the last 6 months). If I misunderstood, then condition should be `where date_column < trunc(sysdate) - 180`.

Comment: Exactly! I tried " where date_column < trunc(sysdate) - 180 " and now shows me what i was expecting! Thanks for the help!